# EF Core 5 couldn't trigger stored procedure and output parameters doesn't have results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I tried to run the stored procedure in the `Sql Server Management Studio`, it works fine, data inserted into the database and it prints output, but when executing in EF Core 5 it doesn't work both output and insert data from stored procedure logic.  Below is my implementation, I use static data just to show you what lies ahead for stored procedures input.

```cs
var output1 = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@OUTPUT1",
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Size = -1
};

var output2 = new SqlParameter
{
     ParameterName = "@OUTPUT2",
     Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt
};

var output3 = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@OUTPUT3",
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt
};

var input1 = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@ID_GUID",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
    Value = Guid.NewGuid()
};
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"EXEC [dbo].[sp_create_job] @ID_GUID, 1568, 'Part-Time', 2, 'Principal Software Engineer', @OUTPUT1 OUT, @OUTPUT2 OUT, @OUTPUT3", input1, output1, output2, output3);
```

**Stored Procedure Input Parameter**

```sql
     @InputX UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,@Input0 BIGINT
    ,@Input1 NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@Input2 NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@Input3 NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@Input4 INT
    ,@Input5 DATE
    ,@Input6 DATE
    ,@Input7 NVARCHAR(1000)
    ,@Input8 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Input9 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Input10 NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@Input11 NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@Input12 NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@Input13 NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@Input14 DATE
    ,@Input15 DATE
    ,@Input16 DATE
    ,@Input17 BIT
    ,@Input18 VARBINARY(16)
    ,@Input19 NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@Input20 NVARCHAR(500)
    ,@Input21 NVARCHAR(20)
    ,@Input22 NVARCHAR(6200)
    ,@Input23 BIGINT OUTPUT
    ,@Input24 BIGINT OUTPUT
    ,@Input25 NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
```

*Update*: Above list is the input paramter for my stored procedures, I can only show these inputs only and contents are prohibited.

What I want to achieve is to display the output parameters and also trigger the stored procedure.

Comment: Where is passing parameters to `ExecuteSqlRaw`?

Comment: hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv I updated the question please check thanks :)

Comment: Hello, does anyone having the same issue as mine?

Comment: Can you post your stored procedure pls, since you have very strange input parameters.

Comment: Hi @Sergey, I can only show you the input parameters, content are not available

Comment: @Sergey, updated please check

Comment: Is anyone still available for help?